# _beginthreadex with member functions

Tags: c++

I'm not sure I'm going about this in the right way, but I'm working with member functions and threads in C++ and Visual Studio 2013.

Other answers I've found said that I must cast my member function as a static function, which allows me to create that thread.  The problem I have is that I cannot call any other member functions that also aren't static.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
//Start the thread for the receive function
    receiveMessageHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &foo::receiveMessageThread, (void*)0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall foo::receiveMessageThread(void *threadToStart)
{
    foo::receiveMessages(); //Non-static member function!
    return 0;
}
```

The non-static member function receiveMessageThread can't be cast as a static member variable either since it uses private member variables.

Any ideas?  Is there a better way to begin a thread here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this is solved by passing "this" object (i.e. instance) as a parameter to the static function:

```
class foo
{
public:
    void startTheThread()
    {
        //Start the thread for the receive function (note "this")
        receiveMessageHandle = 
            _beginthreadex(0, 0, &foo::receiveMessageThread, this, 0, 0);
    }
private:
    void receiveMessages()
    {
    }

    static unsigned int __stdcall receiveMessageThread(void *p_this)
    {
        foo* p_foo = static_cast<foo*>(p_this);
        p_foo->receiveMessages(); // Non-static member function!
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned int receiveMessageHandle;
};

// somewhere
foo* the_foo = ...
the_foo->startTheThread();
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I now see how close I was, I was just missing that last step.

Also I think the p_this->receiveMessages(); should be foo->receiveMessages (at least that's what the IDE likes).

Comment: I'm getting a linker error when I try to do the_foo->startTheThread();  I've spend the last few hours trying to figure this out to no avail.  Does it have something to do with the CLI?

LMK2028: unresolved token

Comment: Hmmm it seems that this is unrelated.. which symbol is undefined?

Comment: I agree.  I've been playing around a bunch and it seems to be related to my complete lack of understanding of CLI haha.  I moved everything out of a class and that didn't help, similar error.  I'm trying to create a dll that contains all this functionality into something like an API.  here's the whole error:
1>fooConsoleApp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000036) "void * __cdecl fooAssembly::startReceiveThread(void)" (?startReceiveThread@fooAssembly@@$$FYAPAXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

Comment: Have you tried to just move the function body out of the class?

Comment: It is out of the class right now, everything was moved to within the namespace of the dll and just called directly from the console app.  I think I might go do some heavy reading and come back to this.  Thanks!